# How to click on a td class in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Python and i've got some issues.
From a websites, there's a calendar where users have to manually click on the date.

My issue is I'd like to click on a specific date with the Selenium code (.click()).
I haven't found the way of selecting a date (for example the 27th) and allow Selenium to click on it.

Thanks for your help !

Below the following html code :

```
<div class="calendar" style="display: block; top: 515.667px; left: 50px;">
    <div class="month dual">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <span class="prev arrow" style="display: none;">
                <span class="icons-arrow_black_left"></span>
                <span class="next arrow" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span class="icons-arrow_black_right"></span>
                <h1 data-automation-id="12">Décembre 2019</h1>
            </header>
            <table class="body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>L</th>
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>J</th>
                        <th>V</th>
                        <th>S</th>
                    </tr>
                    <div class="calendar" style="display: block; top: 515.667px; left: 50px;">
    <div class="month dual">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <span class="prev arrow" style="display: none;">
                <span class="icons-arrow_black_left"></span>
                <span class="next arrow" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span class="icons-arrow_black_right"></span>
                <h1 data-automation-id="12">Décembre 2019</h1>
            </header>
            <table class="body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>L</th>
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>J</th>
                        <th>V</th>
                        <th>S</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class>1</td>
                        <td class>2</td>
                        <td class>3</td>
                        <td class>4</td>
                        <td class>5</td>
                        <td class>6</td>
                        <td class>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class>8</td>
                        <td class>9</td>
                        <td class>10</td>
                        <td class>11</td>
                        <td class>12</td>
                        <td class>13</td>
                        <td class>14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class>15</td>
                        <td class>16</td>
                        <td class>17</td>
                        <td class>18</td>
                        <td class>19</td>
                        <td class>20</td>
                        <td class>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class>22</td>
                        <td class>23</td>
                        <td class>24</td>
                        <td class>25</td>
                        <td class>26</td>
                        <td class>27</td>
                        <td class>28</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class>29</td>
                        <td class>30</td>
                        <td class>31</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
xpath = '//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]'
```

for 27.th day in month

Comment: But how could I do it automatically if I had to choose another date ?

Comment: You could create dictionary for each day, like d = { 1 : 'xpath1', ..., 27: 'xpath27'...}, then you can use d[27] or similar

Comment: The dictionary is a good idea. And one more thing do you know how to count the number of 'tr' ? I used this ```len(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr"))``` but I've got an error ```TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()```

Comment: elements not element

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this in XPATH:

```
//div[@class='calendar']//table//td[text()=27]
```

and no dictionaries needed